# OpenCV and C++: Error with Traincascade: A Practical Issue

Tags: c++, opencv, classification, cascade

In the past few days I've been investigating the createsamples and traincascade methods in order to generate a car cascaded classifier. Such as myself, many people find themselves not having a clue about how to get past all the errors and problems, so in this post I'll explain my procedure and reasoning as well as I can, as well as my problem.

To give a little more context, in the past I implemented myself a boosted classifier with Haar features but since the method was not cascaded it was very slow. I am, however, very well acquainted with the method behind the cascaded classification.

**Problem: Car classification on images**

I downloaded a dataset (set of images) that provides 550 positive windows (100w x 40h images with cars) and 500 negative windows (100w x 40h images without cars), and I intend to use this data to train the cascaded classifier.

**STEP 1 - Generate the .dat files for creating samples**

The createsamples application needs a .dat file with the information about the positive and negative samples. I generated two .dat files, one with positive windows and other with negative windows:

**positive.dat example structure:**

```
CarData\TrainImages\POS\pos-0.pgm 1 0 0 100 40

CarData\TrainImages\POS\pos-1.pgm 1 0 0 100 40 (and more 548 lines of this)
```

The number 1 indicates that there is one object in the entire image, and the next 4 integers represent the bounding box that has the object (the entire image in this example)

**negative.dat example structure:**

```
CarData\TrainImages\NEG\neg-0.pgm

CarData\TrainImages\NEG\neg-1.pgm(and more 498 lines of this)
```

**STEP 2 - Generate .vec files**

To do this I use the createsamples.exe application with the following command line:

```
: createsamples.exe -info path/positive.dat -vec samples.vec -bg negative.dat -w 100 -h 40 -num 550
```

So far so good, the samples.vec file is generated with no issue.

**STEP 3 - Train the cascaded classifier**

To do this I use the traincascade application with the following command line:

```
: traincascade.exe -data CarDetector -vec path/samples.vec -bg path/negative.dat -numStages 15 -stageType BOOST -featureType HAAR -w 100 -h 40 -bt DAB -maxDepth 2 -mode ALL
```

**PARAMETERS EXPLAINED:**

numStages(15): means that I want my classifier will have 15 decision stages.

stageType(BOOST): each stage is a boosted classifier

featureType(HAAR): use haar features for classification. HOG and LBP also available.

w(100): detection window width

h(40): detection window height

bt(DAB): means I want to use Discrete Adaboost (rather than logitboost and others)

maxDepth(2): means each weak classifier will use 3 features for classification

-mode(ALL): I think it means it will use all variety of haar features.

**ERROR**

When I run the command, the program crashes immediately with no error message, so I am completely clueless as to what I am doing wrong.
I'm hoping that someone experienced in this matter will identify the problem with my procedure, as this is an issue shared by many people who are trying to use this application.

[image: problem]

Regards!

**IMPORTAT - EDIT 2:**

I tried to train a classifier with the deprecated app haartraining, just to see if I could get more information, and this is what happens:

[image: image description]

Comment: And what is happening after pressing "Retry" to Debug as suggested?

Comment: Another dialog appears saying that the application stopped working. I've tried to attach the process to the Visual Studio and then press retry, just to see if VS would show me where it crashes, but no luck with that.

Comment: Make sure sure the file is open/found. Just resolved the similar issue here -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19401167/error-r6010-why-is-it-called.

Answer (score 1):

You are using images of size 100x40. (-w 100 -h 40) Apparently OpenCV precomputes all the possible features and that leads to a bad allocation (I get a bad alloc on my system). Try scaling down to 25x10 and see if that still happens.