# Error R6010. Why is it called?

Tags: c++, abort

I am creating a basic 2D game. My code works perfectly well in Visual Studio 2010. However when i create a .exe and run it, I receive a message stating "Debug Error, R6010, Abort has been called".

By starting from scratch and adding bits of code until I find the error I have narrowed the problem down to the code below. I have included the whole function but can provide more code if necessary.

Answers to other peoples questions suggest that the problem is something to do with an error not being caught (I have experimented with try/catch statements to no avail). However I can not see where as the code runs without them in debug mode.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful.

```
  void initGUI()
{

//Button Types correspond to which section of the screen the button will be displayed in. 
//type 1 = Top Bar,
//type 2 = Main Body,
//type 3 = Overlay window (gui1 only)

bool endFile = false;
string totalGUIString;
string text;
vector<string> stringVector;

//Open the file
cout << "Opening file buttons.txt" << endl;
fstream textFile;
textFile.open("buttons.txt");

//Read the first line and determine the amount of GUI's that need to be created
textFile >> totalGUIString;
int totalGUIs = convertStringToInt(totalGUIString);
cout << "Total number of GUI's to load = " << totalGUIs << endl;

//Create the correct amount of GUI's
for(int j = 0; j < totalGUIs; j++)
{
    guiMatrix.push_back(gui(j));
}

textFile >> text;

while(endFile == false) //Search through the main body of the file
{
    //textFile >> text;

    if(text == "END") 
    {
        endFile = true;
        cout << "Reached the end of the file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        stringVector.push_back(text);
        //cout << "PushBack:"  << text << endl;

        if(text == "E")
        {
            //Use vector to populate the button constructor
            int button0 = convertStringToInt(stringVector[0]);
            int button1 = convertStringToInt(stringVector[1]);
            string button2 = stringVector[2];
            int button3 = convertStringToInt(stringVector[3]);

            //cout << "TESTING:: " << button0 << " " << button1 << " " << button2 << " " << button3 << endl;

            guiMatrix[button0].addButton(button1, button2, button3);

            stringVector.clear();

        }

        textFile >> text;
    }
}

textFile.close();

//For every guiMatrix print the button list to cout. 
for(int a = 0; a < totalGUIs; a++)
{
    guiMatrix[a].printButtonMatrix();
}
}
```

The text file being inputted looks like this:
The number at the top defines how many GUI pages I want to create.
The format of each entry is as follows: Page Number, Location handle, name, duration of effect, End

```
5

0 2 Explore 0 E
0 2 Technologies 0 E
0 2 Buildings 0 E
0 2 Workers 0 E

0 1 Scoop_Water 10 E
0 1 Collect_Water 10 E
0 1 Forage 10 E
0 1 Gather_Twigs 10 E
0 1 Fell_Trees 10 E

1 2 Enter 0 E

1 1 Build_Road 1 E

2 2 Explore 0 E
2 2 Main 0 E
2 2 Buildings 0 E
2 2 Workers 0 E

2 1 Backpack 0 E
2 1 Hand_Cart 0 E

3 2 Explore 0 E
3 2 Main 0 E
3 2 Technologies 0 E
3 2 Workers

3 1 Build_Hut 0 E

4 2 Explore 0 E
4 2 Main 0 E
4 2 Technologies 0 E
4 2 Buildings 0 E


END
```

Comment: There should be an option to build for release, try that...

Comment: Just tried in release mode. The error is still there.

Comment: Sure the file is open/found?

Comment: Its always the simple things. For some reason the .exe wasn't finding the .txt with the rest of the files. I have copied it into the same folder as the .exe and it works. Ill have to make sure that's flagged up by the program in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors were being thrown when `.png` files could not be found by the `.exe.` There was no provision for what should be done if these files were not found.

Solved by moving relevant `.png` files into the same folder as the executable.